# How do I write a hash function with a unique (string, integer) pair as a key?

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

Specifically, I'm storing URLs and ports and storing them in a table. A pair would be ("www.beej.us", 80) or ("8.8.8.8", 22). Does it make sense to append the integer onto the string and hash on the final string?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: this is a programming philosophy question, not a 'need help programming' question.

Comment: Where would be the best place to ask this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performance and minimizing collisions, you would better write a hash function as follows:

```
hash(host) * prime_greater_than_65536 + port
```